# Typescript - Define interface for a very general function

Tags: typescript

I have provided an example for a function `functionCaller`. it requires a function, any kind of function.

```
const functionCaller = (func: any /* how to define this general func? */) => {
  func();
};

functionCaller((hello: string) => {});
functionCaller(() => {});
functionCaller(() => new Promise((resolve) => {}));
```

How is it possible to define such a function argument without resorting to `any`?

Answer (score 1):

If this type is such as flexible, you will always end to an `any`.

However, the function type will be like so

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

const functionCaller = (func: AnyFunction) => {
    func();
}
```

Or, you can be more precise by doing generic types.

```
type Args = any[] | never;
type AnyFunction<TArgs extends Args, TResult> = (...args: TArgs) => TResult;

const functionCaller = <TResult>(func: AnyFunction<any[], TResult>) => {
    func();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
const functionCaller = (func: Function) => {
  func();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the following, which will allow you to have the type of the returned data :

```
function functionCaller<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: T): ReturnType<T> {
    return func();
}

const funcA = (hello: string) => { };
const funcB = () => { };
const funcC = () => new Promise((resolve) => { })

const typeA = functionCaller<typeof funcA>(funcA);

const typeB = functionCaller<typeof funcB>(funcB);

const typeC = functionCaller<typeof funcC>(funcC);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=51&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSsEGECGAbbBTAJwB4AVRPADyjzABMBnRACgDo3MCBzegLkUzABPANoBdAJSIAvAD5+QmUxQQ+JcXwBKeKCAJgSggA55ScgN4AoRNcQFtupMqbiA3BYC+FixAT0oycAgAQWlmAAs8XDg+PwIYME5JWUQzRHc3HzA-AMgAIVDnaXM0jN9-ZXQCpLkwPAB3RAAFAjgAWxh6PCYmO3o4bAA3PGqUtPEvTOyoIzwQqRzoeDAsXEIiaeM4YAWgxWUg1wmyxA28fPnlNGWcfGJTrYXcvcDcw+9j08qLwKuV2-WZg8Ks9IOhXEA)

Answer (score -1):

You can define it this way:

```
const functionCaller = (func: () => any) => {
  func();
};
```

Hope this helps.